# How can I fix this textbook program to add polynomials in C++?

Tags: c++, polynomials

I am just kind of starting to code and this was in a book that I am using to learn C++. It should be working straight from the book and I can't figure out how to fix it.

I think the problem might be because it lacks the constant operator but if you add it in doesn't that prevent you from modifying the value?

The book is by Drozdek titles Data Structures and Algorithms in C++ if you need that. Thanks for the help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Variable {
public:
    char id;
    int exp;
    Variable() { // required by <vector>;
    }
    Variable(char c, int i) {
        id = c; exp = i;
    }
    bool operator== (const Variable& v) const { 
        return id  == v.id  && exp == v.exp;
    }
    bool operator< (const Variable& v) const { // used by sort();
        return id < v.id;
    }
};

class Term {
public:
    Term() {
        coeff = 0;
    }
    int coeff;
    vector<Variable> vars;
    bool operator== (const Term&) const;
    bool operator!= (const Term& term) const { // required by <list>
        return !(*this == term);
    }
    bool operator< (const Term&) const;
    bool operator> (const Term& term) const {  // required by <list>
        return *this != term && (*this < term);
    }
    int min(int n, int m) const {
        return (n < m) ? n : m;
    }
};

class Polynomial {
public:
    Polynomial() {
    }
    Polynomial operator+ (Polynomial&);
    void error(char *s) {
        cerr << s << endl; exit(1);
    }
private:
    list<Term> terms;
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Polynomial& polyn) {
        char ch, sign, coeffUsed, id;
        int exp;
        Term term;
        in >> ch;
        while (true) {
            coeffUsed = 0;
            if (!isalnum(ch) && ch != ';' && ch != '-' && ch != '+')
                 polyn.error("Wrong character entered2");
            sign = 1;
            while (ch == '-' || ch == '+') { // first get sign(s) of Term
                 if (ch == '-')
                       sign *= -1;
                 ch = in.get();
                 if (isspace(ch))
                       in >> ch;
            }
            if (isdigit(ch)) {              // and then its coefficient;
                 in.putback(ch);
                 in >> term.coeff;
                 ch = in.get();
                 term.coeff *= sign;
                 coeffUsed = 1;
            }
            else term.coeff = sign;
        int i;
            for (int i = 0; isalnum(ch); i++) { // process this term:
                id = ch;                    // get a variable name
                ch = in.get();
                if (isdigit(ch)) {          // and an exponent (if any);
                     in.putback(ch);
                     in >> exp >> ch;
                }
                else exp = 1;
                term.vars.push_back(Variable(id,exp));
            }
            polyn.terms.push_back(term);    // and include it in the linked list;
            term.vars.resize(0);    
            if (isspace(ch))
                 in >> ch;
            if (ch == ';')                  // finish if a semicolon is entered;
                 if (coeffUsed || i > 0)
                      break;
                 else polyn.error("Term is missing");  // e.g., 2x - ; or just ';'
            else if (ch != '-' && ch != '+')           // e.g., 2x  4y;
                 polyn.error("wrong character entered");
        }
        for (list<Term>::iterator it = polyn.terms.begin(); it != polyn.terms.end(); it++)
            if (it->vars.size() > 1)
                sort(it->vars.begin(),it->vars.end());
        return in;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Polynomial& polyn) {
        int afterFirstTerm = 0, i;
        for (list<Term>::const_iterator pol = polyn.terms.begin(); pol != polyn.terms.end(); pol++) {
            out.put(' ');
            if (pol->coeff < 0)             // put '-' before polynomial
                 out.put('-');              // and between terms (if needed);
            else if (afterFirstTerm)        // don't put '+' in front of
                 out.put('+');              // polynomial;
            afterFirstTerm++;
            if (abs(pol->coeff) != 1)       // print a coefficient
                 out << ' ' << abs(pol->coeff);// if it is not 1 nor -1, or
            else if (pol->vars.size() == 0) // the term has only a coefficient
                 out << " 1";               
            else out.put(' ');
            for (i = 1; i <= pol->vars.size(); i++) {
                 out << pol->vars[i-1].id;       // print a variable name
                 if (pol->vars[i-1].exp != 1)    // and an exponent, only
                      out << pol->vars[i-1].exp; // if it is not 1;
            }
        }
        out << endl;
        return out;
    }
};

// two terms are equal if all varibles are the same and
// corresponding variables are raised to the same powers;
// the first cell of the node containing a term is excluded
// from comparison, since it stores coefficient of the term;

bool Term::operator== (const Term& term) const {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < min(vars.size(),term.vars.size()) &&
                    vars[i] == term.vars[i]; i++);
    return i == vars.size() && vars.size() == term.vars.size();
}

bool Term::operator< (const Term& term2) const { // used by sort();
    if (vars.size() == 0)
        return false;           // *this is just a coefficient;
    else if (term2.vars.size() == 0)
        return true;            // term2 is just a coefficient;
    for (int i = 0; i < min(vars.size(),term2.vars.size()); i++)
        if (vars[i].id < term2.vars[i].id)
             return true;       // *this precedes term2;
        else if (term2.vars[i].id < vars[i].id)
             return false;      // term2 precedes *this;
        else if (vars[i].exp < term2.vars[i].exp)
             return true;       // *this precedes term2;
        else if (term2.vars[i].exp < vars[i].exp)
             return false;      // term2 precedes *this;
    return ((int)vars.size() - (int)term2.vars.size() < 0) ? true : false;
}

Polynomial Polynomial::operator+ (Polynomial& polyn2) {
    Polynomial result;
    list<Term>::iterator p1, p2;
    bool erased;
    for (p1 = terms.begin(); p1 != terms.end(); p1++) // create a new polyn
        result.terms.push_back(*p1);                  // from copies of *this
    for (p1 = polyn2.terms.begin(); p1 != polyn2.terms.end(); p1++) // and
        result.terms.push_back(*p1);                  // polyn2;
    for (p1 = result.terms.begin(); p1 != result.terms.end(); ) {
        for (p2 = p1, p2++, erased = false; p2 != result.terms.end(); p2++)
            if (*p1 == *p2) {             // if two terms are equal (except
                 p1->coeff += p2->coeff;  // for the coefficient), add the
                 result.terms.erase(p2);  // two coefficients and erase
                 if (p1->coeff == 0)      // a redundant term; if the 
                     result.terms.erase(p1);// coefficient in retained term 
                 erased = true;             // is zero, erase the term as well;
                 break;
            }
        if (erased)        // restart processing from the beginning
             p1 = result.terms.begin();  // if any node was erased;
        else p1++;
    }
    result.terms.sort();
    return result;
}

int main() {
    Polynomial polyn1, polyn2;
    cout << "Enter two polynomials, each ended with a semicolon:\n";
    cin  >> polyn1 >> polyn2;
    cout << "The result is:\n" << polyn1 + polyn2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: `Variable() { /* required by <vector> */ }` - `Variable() = default;` would be better, since then, at least, your default constructor is still *trivial*.

Comment: `// required by <vector>;` It actually isn't - if you `emplace_back` into a `std::vector` - you don't need a default constructor.

Comment: You use unitialized variable `i` in the line `if (coeffUsed || i > 0)`

Comment: HolyBlackCat, it will not compile when I use Putty to run it. Are you saying it should compile as is?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Neither does `push_back` require it. Only `resize` does.

Comment: `Term() { coeff = 0; }` *really* wants to be using the constructors initialization list and be written as `Term() : coeff(0) { }` . *Never* use the constructor body when the initialization list can do the job.

Comment: @crofab Please put the full compiler error message into the question.

Comment: @crofab "it will not compile when I use Putty to run it" - `putty` is a program to establish a remote shell connection to another machine. How does that in *any way* have anything to do with whether or not your C++ program is valid or not??? Except that you may be using a different compiler/platform/standard library on said remote machine.. but I don't see why use of *putty* is relevant..

Comment: If this code is from a book this is a bad book. This is perfect example of badly written code. Anyway more or less it [works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7XEL4mi77CxjjvlV). I've found this book and it has a bad opinion (6 / 10) - please change the book.

Comment: Turn on the compiler warnings and turn them up loud. Compiler warnings are messages from the compiler telling you that your code compiles, but probably will not do what you expect it to do. Do not ignore the warnings. Understand what the compiler is telling you and then fix the problems.

Answer (score 2):

On line 52, the error function should take a `const char*`, rather than a `char*`:

```
    void error(char* s) { // WRONG
```

```
    void error(const char *s) { // RIGHT
        cerr << s << endl; exit(1);
    }
```

This is because strings like `"Hello"` are arrays of `const char`, because you can't modify literals. If you make this change, the code should work. The compiler won't convert pointers to `const` types to regular pointers, because that would break the `const`ness.

Also, on line 82 ad 83, the textbook writes:

```
int i; // Error: i never initialized
for (int i = 0; isalnum(ch); i++) { // process this term:
```

It looks like it was trying to use `i` both inside and outside the for loop, but the author accidentally declared `i` a second time at the start of the loop. We can fix it by doing this:

```
int i = 0; // This is probably what was intended
for(; isalnum(ch); i++) { // process this term:
```

## Why can't I modify string literals?

Imagine if you could do

```
5 = 10; // This is complete and utter nonsense.
```

This doesn't make any sense! You can't assign 5 to 10. In the same way, this is also nonsense:

```
"hello" = "blarg"; // This is also nonsense
```

`"hello"` is always `"hello"`, and never anything else. If the compiler allowed you to write

```
"hello"[0] = 'H'; // This is also nonsense
```

This would be modifying `"hello"`, which could just... break your program. It's wrong; it's evil. In fact, the string literal "hello" might even be placed in a section of memory that's flagged as `const` *by the Operating System itself*.

## Why does the compiler give you the error (or warning)

If you have `char*`, that is a *pointer to a char*. If you have `const char*`, that is a *pointer to a const char*. If you could go from `const char*` to `char*`, this would allow you to modify `const` memory, which could break the program:

```
// If you could do this, you could modify "hello"
// Modifying "hello" is nonsense, so this should be nonsense too:
char* s = "hello"; 
s[0] = 'H'; // How you'd modify "hello"
```

As a result, string literals can only be assigned to `const char*`:

```
// Because s contains const chars, elements of s can't be modified so this is fine
const char* s = "hello"; // This is OK
```

## Why did the textbook contain the error?

The language *used* to let people do really unsafe stuff, like modifying string literals. This is extremely bad practice and it breaks optimizations the compiler uses to make programs smaller and faster.

The textbook is probably written by someone who's used to writing old, unsafe code.

Comment: This is a good quality answer on a low quality question - somewhat wasted effort. The error/warning you are dissecting here has been discussed to death on stackoverflow already, and while your explanation is good, it's unlikely to ever be found by anyone else... You could consider finding/linking a duplicate instead. But I won't stop you from answering, of course.

Comment: Also `isalnum(ch)` is UB for negative characters, it should've been `isalnum((unsigned char)ch)`...

Comment: WHY WOULD THEY MAKE THAT THE CASE. WHY. ALL THEY HAD TO DO WAS WRITE IT AS `return '0' <= ch && ch <= '9' || 'a' <= ch && ch <= 'z' || 'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z';`

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez Because it is a C library function and supposed to handle the output from the C I/O functions which return `unsigned char` converted to `int` or EOF (a negative constant) as end-of-file marker (which cannot be a representable as `unsigned char` value). Since all character values + EOF cannot fit a `char`, a larger integer type, e.g. `int`, must be used.